# Getting the error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'DynamicServerError' of 'serverHooks' as it is undefined.` when Using nextjs

Tags: next.js

I am using nextjs 13 with glidejs for carousel but anytime I try to get the carousel to run, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'DynamicServerError' of 'serverHooks' as it is undefined.`

I am using the carousel from wind-ui, as [here](https://wind-ui.com/components/carousels/)

Has anyone experienced and solved this error before?

Here is the code as lifted from wind-ui. I am using the react component from wind-ui as is.

```js
    'use client'
    import React, { useEffect } from "react"
    import Glide from "@glidejs/glide"
    
    export default function CarouselLogo() {
      useEffect(() => {
        const slider = new Glide(".glide-09", {
          type: "carousel",
          autoplay: 1,
          animationDuration: 4500,
          animationTimingFunc: "linear",
          perView: 3,
          classes: {
            nav: {
              active: "[&>*]:bg-wuiSlate-700",
            },
          },
          breakpoints: {
            1024: {
              perView: 2,
            },
            640: {
              perView: 1,
              gap: 36,
            },
          },
        }).mount()
    
        return () => {
          slider.destroy()
        }
      }, [])
    
      return (
        <>
          {/*<!-- Component: Testimonial carousel --> */}
          <div className="glide-09 relative w-full">
            {/* <!-- Slides --> */}
            <div data-glide-el="track">
              <ul className="whitespace-no-wrap flex-no-wrap [backface-visibility: hidden] [transform-style: preserve-3d] [touch-action: pan-Y] [will-change: transform] relative flex w-full overflow-hidden p-0">
                <li>
                  <img
                    src="https://Tailwindmix.b-cdn.net/carousel/logos/carousel-logo-image-1.svg"
                    className="m-auto h-20 max-h-full w-auto max-w-full"
                  />
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/*<!-- End Testimonial carousel --> */}
        </>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Please add your code on how you are using the carousel from wind-ui

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate this error by importing `Glide` component directly from the ESM bundle:

```js
import Glide from "@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.esm"
```

Actually, it looks like the intended import path is supposed to be `glide.modular.esm`:

```js
import Glide from "@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.modular.esm";
```

but the two bundles are not identical, and in my tests autoplay doesn't work in the latter option. You can probably try both and see which one works properly in your project.

**Why does this error occur in the first place?**

`@glidejs/glide` package incorrectly points its `main` entry point to UMD bundle rather than CommonJS (actually I do not see CommonJS bundle in the package distribution at all). I'm guessing this UMD/CommonJS mismatch is causing some errors in Next.js transpilation/bundling process. So the real solution here would be for `@glidejs/glide` maintainers to fix `@glidejs/glide` package distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on a hook is what got this working for me. I refactored for you. Cheers!

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useId } from "react"
import Glide from "@glidejs/glide"

const useGlide = () => {
  const glideId = useId()

  useEffect(() => {
    const slider = new Glide(".glide-09", {
      type: "carousel",
      autoplay: 1,
      animationDuration: 4500,
      animationTimingFunc: "linear",
      perView: 3,
      classes: {
        nav: {
          active: "[&>*]:bg-wuiSlate-700",
        },
      },
      breakpoints: {
        1024: {
          perView: 2,
        },
        640: {
          perView: 1,
          gap: 36,
        },
      },
    }).mount()

    return () => {
      slider.destroy()
    }
  }, [glideId])

  return glideId
}

export default function CarouselLogo() {   
  const glideId = useGlide();
  return (
    <>
      {/*<!-- Component: Testimonial carousel --> */}
      <div id={glideId} className="relative w-full">
        {/* <!-- Slides --> */}
        <div data-glide-el="track">
          <ul className="whitespace-no-wrap flex-no-wrap [backface-visibility: hidden] [transform-style: preserve-3d] [touch-action: pan-Y] [will-change: transform] relative flex w-full overflow-hidden p-0">
            <li>
              <img
                src="https://Tailwindmix.b-cdn.net/carousel/logos/carousel-logo-image-1.svg"
                className="m-auto h-20 max-h-full w-auto max-w-full"
              />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/*<!-- End Testimonial carousel --> */}
    </>
  )
}
```